# Внешний ключ по двум полям

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть три таблицы

```
english_words:
id INT | word VARCAHR
-----------------------
1      | word1
2      | word2

english_phrases:
id INT  | phrase VARCHAR
------------------------
1       | phrase1
2       | phrase2

russian_translations:
id INT | from_type ENUM(word, phrase) | from_id | translation
----------------------------------------------------------------
1      | word                         | 1       | Перевод word1
2      | word                         | 2       | Перевод word2
3      | phrase                       | 1       | Перевод phrase1
4      | phrase                       | 2       | Перевод phrase3
```

В первой - хранится список слов, во второй - список фраз, в третей перевода для первой и второй таблицы. Тип сущности, определяется по полю `from_type`, id сущности - по полю `from_id`.

Собственно вопрос: существует ли возможность, задать внешний ключ по полям  `from_type` и `from_id`, с учетом значения в `from_type` ?
Т.е. если в `from_type` значение word, то ссылаться на english_words.id, а если phrase, то на english_phrases.id.

Comment: Такой возможности нет. Предполагается, что в правильно составленной реляционной модели первые две таблицы будут одной таблицей с указанием типа записи (или будет общая для них таблица, а специфическая информация будет лежать в отдельных)

Comment: @Mile Я почему-то об этом же подумал, только после того как задал вопрос. Да, действительно, первую и вторую таблицу можно объединить в одну и добавить поле `type`.